# Relation between exponential random variables and their min

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

If
$$U=exponential(\lambda), \quad V = exponential(\mu)$$
and if they are independent, then $T = \min (U,V)$ is exponential $(\lambda + \mu)$.

How do we show that $P(T = U) = \lambda / (\lambda  + \mu)$? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(T=U) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(U<V) = \iint\limits_{u,v\,:\, u\,<\,v} e^{-\lambda u} e^{-\mu v} (\lambda\mu\,d(u,v)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \left( e^{-\lambda u} \int_u^\infty e^{-\mu v} (\mu\,dv) \right) (\lambda \, du) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}.
\end{align}